# Find the exact critical numbers for $f(x) = 3x - \sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus

I found the derivative of the function which I believe is $3-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ but I am not sure how to find the $x$ value for the critical number.

Comment: The most common definition of critical number is a number where the derivative is $0$ *or does not exist*. That gives us two values. Sometimes, the endpoints (if any) of the interval of definition are included.

Comment: What is a *critical number* ?

Answer (score 1):

One has, for $x>0$,
$$
f'(x)=3-\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}=\frac{6\sqrt{x}-1}{2\sqrt{x}}
$$ giving, for $f'(x)=0$, 
$$
\quad 6\sqrt{x}-1=0, \quad x=\frac1{36}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Set $0=3-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ and solve for $x$